# ListView events set in the properties don't work

Tags: c#, events, listview

I am trying to use the MouseClick event from the properties of a listView to handle left and right mouse clicks.

Unfortunately the event never seems to fire. (Double clicked on the event to create a property, entered a bit of simple code and placed a breakpoint on the first line). The same is true of several other events listed in the properties (ItemSelectionChanged seems to work but the other events I have tried don't fire.

Here is the code added:

- In form.designer.cs:

  this.listView1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.listView1_MouseClick);
- In form.cs:

  private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
   Some code
  }

That method never gets called when I click on the listview. The listview is inside a tab on top of the stack.

I guess I am probably forgetting something very basic but what?

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot, that does it. Can you make your comment into a question so I can accept it? BTW, is there a reference that explains exactly when each event is triggered? 

I checked msdn and tried both "click" and "mouseclick" before posting this question and under both it claims that the event is raised when the control is clicked, without mention of any restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView is a bit unusual, its MouseClick event doesn't fire unless you click an item in the view.  Workaround is to use the MouseDown or MouseUp event instead.  You typically are much more interested in the ItemSelectionChanged event btw.  You probably need its HitTest() method to see exactly what was clicked if you use MouseDown/Up.

Comment: Thanks. For now, I just trying to create a context menu for each item and for the list view in general if the user clicks a spot without an item.

Comment: Mention these things in your question so we don't have to guess at it.  You do need MouseUp and HitTest.

Comment: Thanks. I was mostly wondering why my events weren't firing up. What are the advantage of using "MouseUp" over "MouseDown"?  And for HitTest, I was planning on using "if(item.Bounds.Contains(new Point(e.X, e.Y)))" which seems to work ok. Is HitTest providing something more?

Comment: Just right-click your browser.  Click slow and notice that it is the MouseUp event that displays the context menu.  And yes, this is intentional, it allows the user to correct an accidental click.  HitTest() tells you which of many sub-parts of the ListView got clicked.  There are many in Details view for example.